# How to open file in QuickOffice from my app?

Tags: ios, ms-office, quicklook, quickoffice

I need to open MS Office files from my application. I have implemented it with the help of QuickLook (QLPreviewController). But I want to open files within QuickOffice application.

In Safari (it uses QuickLook to view MS Office files) I see a button "Open in QuickView".
So I wonder how one can do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, you can present an "Open in..." menu with either the `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` or the `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method.

There is no way for third-party apps to display a direct "Open in App XYZ" button, like Safari does.